# First declared closure in SwiftUI is called but not others

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 4 closure in button action but only the first one is triggered

```swift
                Button(action: { self.showScanner = true }) {
                    ButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "IN")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner) {
                    QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
                        debugPrint("IN - \(code)")
                    })
                }

                Button(action: { self.showScanner = true }) {
                    CloakroomButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "OUT")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner) {
                    QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
                        debugPrint("OUT - \(code)")
                    })
                }


                Button(action: { self.showScanner = true }) {
                    ButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "OWNER")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner) {
                    QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
                        debugPrint("Owner - \(code)")
                    })
                }
```

```swift
struct QRCodeRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable  {

    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var didCodeFound: (String) -> ()

}
```

The issue is that if i tap on other button like "out" and "owner" then the closure of the "in" button is triggered.
I always have "debugPrint("IN - (code)")" called.

Any ideas, what's wrong in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use different variables for each `.sheet`

Comment: How do you set a variable for a sheet?!

Comment: Declare a different variable for each `sheet`: `@State var showScannerIN = false`, `@State var showScannerOUT = false` and `@State var showScannerOWNER = false`

Comment: Thanks @krjw ! Indeed, it works by declaring specific variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple sheets, please use `item`, not `isPresented`

```
 extension String: Identifiable{
       public var id : String {get{self}}
   }
        @State var activeString : String?

         var body: some View {
     {
                   ForEach(["IN", "Out", "Owner"], id:  \.self ){ str in
                    Button(action: { self.activeString = str} ) {
                   // ButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "IN")
                        Text(str)
                }}.sheet(item: self.$activeString) {
                        Text($0)
 //                            QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
 //                                debugPrint("IN - \(code)")
 //                            })
                }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but what if you want to display differently 4 buttons ?  If i use the "for loop" it's will be hard to customize the layout. isn't it?

Comment: This is actually a good solution... you could pass in the array of `Strings`... which would then be iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove that boolean variable `showScanner` or make it type String or other (int) type. For maintain all 3 state you want in functionality

Try below code.

```swift
@State var showScanner = ""

Button(action: { self.showScanner = "IN" }) {
  ButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "IN")
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner == "IN") {
  QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
    debugPrint("IN - \(code)")
  })
}

Button(action: { self.showScanner = "OUT" }) {
  CloakroomButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "OUT")
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner == "OUT") {
  QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
    debugPrint("OUT - \(code)")
  })
}


Button(action: { self.showScanner = "OWNER" }) {
  ButtonContent(buttonTextContent: "OWNER")
}
.sheet(isPresented: self.$showScanner == "OWNER") {
  QRCodeRepresentable(isPresented: self.$showScanner, didCodeFound: { code in
    debugPrint("Owner - \(code)")
  })
}
```